# notepad++ mark all with different colors

Tags: notepad++

So there is a feature to mark the filtered text in notepad++. So once I marked the text when I search again for some other text I want to mark it with different colour.

```
Mark All
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So when you select the filter text first time, right click and select a `style token` to apply. And then go ahead with your next filter selection.

An example image is below , where I first filtered `PM` text and right clicked on it and applied a style token. After which I went on to select a new filter text `datetime`

[image]

Comment: I am using notepad++ v6.2 and can not see any style token on right click after text selection....

Comment: @user2634485 Have a look in NPPs config folder (`%appdata%\Notepad++\`) if the contextMenu.xml is there. If no: that would be the answer; if yes: it might be defect.
You can grab the original standard contextMenu.xml from http://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/notepadplus_repository/trunk/PowerEditor/src/contextMenu.xml?content-type=text%2Fplain&view=co and place it into the config folder (or replace the existing xml).

Comment: For those like me using a non-default theme, you have to set the different "Mark Styles" in Settings > Style Configurator.

Comment: "right click and select a style token to apply" - right click what?

Comment: @Line `select the filter text first time` ; right click over the selected text

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not the answer for initial question :( Like this you can highlight only tags (whole words). And the author asked about Mark tab from search dialog. Where you can search any complex text. And the answer to initial question - sadly no :(
GitHub issue: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4535